# add 2 elements highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have armed most of the graph, but I need to add two things (picture), the yellow number and the arrow with the rectangle, is there a way to do it?

[image: https://imgur.com/zGx70wt]

```
  Highcharts.chart('grafico6', {
        colors: ['#8BDD8C','#FF685F'],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1,2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: -40,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
              labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                   return this.value+"%";
                }
              }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none',
                    format: '{y} %',
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Excelencia',
            data: [['25',50], 30, 30, 60, 20,50, 30, 40, 70, 20,50, 30, 40, 70, 20,50, 30, 40, 70, 20,50, 30, 40, 70, 20]
        }, {
            name: 'Deficiencia',
            data: [-20, -40, -30, -30, -10,-20, -40, -30, -20, -10,-20, -40, -30, -20, -10,-20, -40, -30, -20, -10,-20, -40, -30, -20, -10]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "add two things"? How do you want to add them? Try to be more precise.

Comment: hello I need to add the yellow numbers that are seen above the columns, in addition to that rectangle with an arrow that says [inmobiliaria]

Comment: Again, what do you mean saying "add"? How do you want to add them?